# Is it possible to combine unity3d with php?

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

I would like to build web browser game using php.
I need graphics so I searched on the web and found option to design 3d model by blender and there is option to transfer/export the model and its object to web.
until here it is excellent for me.
the question is, is there option to control the object and model by using php?
thanks

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say no, since PHP is server side. But don't take my word for it though

Comment: Yes but I can add java script for client side ? and php for database and to manga the game. what you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Tempests' Web Suite: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/17674-Unity-Web-Suite-(Examples-Tutorials)

Scroll down to PHPHandler ;)